# Glom: How to include field-specific defaults

Tags: python, glom

How can one include field-specific *defaults* in glom's output?

For example, I can include "constants" like this:

```py
from glom import Spec, Literal
extract = Spec({'A': 'a', 'B': Literal(42)}).glom
assert extract({'a': 'life'}) == {'A': 'life', 'B': 42}
```

But how do I specify that 'B' should point to 42 only if 'B' is not in the input? Stepping out of glom I can do this:

```py
from glom import Spec
extract = lambda d: dict(Spec({'A': 'a'}).glom(d), B=d.get('B', 42))
assert extract({'a': 'life'}) == {'A': 'life', 'B': 42}
assert extract({'a': 'life', 'B': 'is short'}) == {'A': 'life', 'B': 'is short'}
```

Surely, there a *glommier* way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(I guess I'll get the glory (and shame for not having known this earlier).)*

The answer is: **Use `glom.Coalesce` with the `default` argument therein**.

The glom-equivalent of the my lambda-using code above:

```py
from glom import Spec, Coalesce
extract = Spec({'A': 'a', 'B': Coalesce('B', default=42)}).glom  # the solution
assert extract({'a': 'life'}) == {'A': 'life', 'B': 42}
assert extract({'a': 'life', 'B': 'is short'}) == {'A': 'life', 'B': 'is short'}
```